Why isn't there a term of temperature in Navier-Stokes equations, despite that gradients of temperature cause transfer of energy?
There is something that I don't understand it at all, which is the non existence of temperature in the Navier-Stokes equation! Isn't these equations are found in the first place to describe the motion of fluids, which of course will be be sensitive to energy behavior, But we know for sure from thermodynamics that when there is gradient of temperature, the heat "energy" transfer from the hotter to colder, and hence temperature can affect the distribution of energy and hence can contribute to dynamics of fluids which are supposed to be described by Navier stokes which does not contain the term of temperature! So I am wondering, where am I wrong? is temperature not affecting the evolution of fluid? or is it that the navier stokes in its most general form does not account for systems in which heat transfers?

You can add any term you like, such as a temperature gradient, chemical gradient, magnetohydrodynamic, etc. The N-S equations as usually cited account for the most common forces encountered – pressure gradients and viscous forces

Check this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54750/

The NS equation is an equation describing the evolution of momentum, not energy. For energy, you have to go and have a look at the energy equation, which is not the NS equation.
NS only couples into temperatures mainly via pressure gradients. Energy transfer via conduction e.g. from hot to cold can work in a perfectly hydrostatic way, and has therefore nothing to do with NS.

The NS equations are strictly mechanical, but the properties in theses equations such as viscosity and density depend on the parameters you identified.

I know @ChetMiller ,But anyway this is not about temperature at all, it does not take the effects of thermal conduction into account when viscosity and density are functions of temperature.. it just describe the evolution of viscosity and density more accurately which by chance are functions of temperature... I think that in order for NS to include thermal interaction, must be coupled with heat or energy equation

Let's discuss 2 different cases: NS equations for compressible flows and for incompressible flows.
Governing equations for compressible flows are a coupled set of PDEs for mass, momentum and energy, along with state and constitutive equations: in general, temperature may appear (or it's likely to appear) in equations of state providing the expressions of internal energy and other thermodynamic variables as functions of the chosen primary unknowns of the problem, and conduction heat flux in energy equation (as an example, think at Fourier law, $\mathbf{q} = - k \nabla T$).
For incompressible flows there are some subtle points to deal with:

the incompressibility constraint kicks thermodynamics out of the problem, forcing a kinematic constraint "a priori": "thermodynamic" variables appearing in the equations lose their thermodynamic meaning;
incompressibility constraint, along with uniform density assumption, makes the subset composed by the incompressibility constraint and momentum equation independent from the energy equation. Thus you can first solve incompressibility+momentum system, containing no "$T$", and later solve for "energy" or "temperature"
some incompressible flow model contains temperature in momentum equation as well. As an example, Boussinesq equations model natural convection in incompressible flows, and temperature appears in a forcing term in momentum equation representing buoyancy due to changes in density driven by changes in temperature.


Nice answer (+1) If the fluid is a mix of 2 constituent particles, one with much larger particle size/mass than the other, then can this fluid be treated approximately as 2 different Navier Stokes fluids coexisting in one pool, since the larger particles presumably interact mainly with its same-sized peers, and the smaller particles presumably interact mainly with its same-sized peers as well?

in non-reactive flows, the 2 species diffuse one into the other, in absence of other physical processes preventing this scenario. If one species has much lower concentration, you can consider it as a diluted specie and its diffusion can be modeled with Fick's law

thank you. Suppose the larger species is 1000x larger and heavier than the smaller one. In this extreme scenario, can the smaller/lighter species be fudged as a "viscosity" factor, and the fluid be modeled just as a single fluid of the larger species?

The Navier-Stokes equation contains no temperature terms because it does not model heat transfer phenomena in fluids.
Adding heat transfer effects to the equations of fluid motion can be done numerically by tracking temperature differences across the surfaces of adjacent fluid cells and accounting for the diffusivity and average temperature of the fluid within each cell.

I think only the first half is marginally correct. The second paragraph is almost entirely wrong.

@KyleKanos that's exactly how we did it at HP for 26 years. William R. Knight wrote the finite element coupled electric/heat transfer/fluid dynamic simulation code (in Fortran77!). Look him up if you desire.

When I was doing it 9 years ago academically (in Fortran90!), heat impacts were considered as a source term in the closure condition (i.e., energy equation). If you have pressure & assume an ideal gas, you don't need temperature separately, just use the gas law. Aside from that, OP is looking for equations, not guidance on solving PDEs

@KyleKanos, temperature was one of our important outputs from the model so we used it expressly. We tracked temperature distributions in the fluid and solid parts of our inkjet printheads as functions of electrical power input. You can provide equations if you wish to Mr. OP. Hope you are doing well.
